# Can't connect to VPS server (Ivacy using OpenVPN, Vultr VPS)

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

Sorry if I come out as a noob to you guys but I only know basic stuff of networking. Now that's out of the way...

I have an Ivacy VPN subscription and a Ubuntu 16.04 VPS on Vultr which I use for my Plex Media Server connected to my Google Suite account. I usually connect to it using both SSH and VNC.

After several painful day I was successfully able to configure Ivacy VPN using OpenVPN and it works just fine if I connect to my VPS using Vultr's own VNC console at their website but I can't connect to it using SSH or VNC from my PC anymore.

When I open it through Vultr's (VNC) console, Firefox, Deluge-web and everything works great but outside my server, nothing works.
And yes... I AM trying to connect to the new IP address of the server.

I'm attaching some configuration files like other guys did in similar posts (Which didn't help BT dubs). Please let me know if any other logs or files are required. Don't ask me for my username and password files because I'm still smarter than TARS and CASE from the movie Interstellar... or not!

ifconfig before VPN

```
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:00:01:65:1a:6b  
      inet addr:45.76.37.239  Bcast:45.76.37.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5400:1ff:fe65:1a6b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:649 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:295859 (295.8 KB)  TX bytes:61162 (61.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

netstat -r before VPN

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         45.76.36.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens3
45.76.36.0      *               255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 ens3
169.254.169.254 45.76.36.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ens3
```

ipconfig before VPN

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

ifconfig after VPN

```
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:00:01:65:1a:6b  
          inet addr:45.76.37.239  Bcast:45.76.37.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5400:1ff:fe65:1a6b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20470 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12551 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25456961 (25.4 MB)  TX bytes:3036507 (3.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1199 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1199 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1030527 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1030527 (1.0 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:37.230.131.175  P-t-P:37.230.131.175  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18067 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:22808772 (22.8 MB)  TX bytes:1261729 (1.2 MB)
```

netstat -r after VPN

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         37.230.131.5    128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
default         45.76.36.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens3
37.230.131.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
37.230.131.2    45.76.36.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ens3
45.76.36.0      *               255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 ens3
128.0.0.0       37.230.131.5    128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
169.254.169.254 45.76.36.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ens3
```

ipconfig after VPN

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

ivacy.conf file for OpenVPN

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote netherlands-tcp.ivacy.net 80
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
tls-auth Wdc.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
mute 20
route-method exe
route-delay 2
float
auth-user-pass login.conf
auth-retry interact
ifconfig-nowarn
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
redirect-gateway def1
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<I removed the certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
```

Comment: Do you know if fail2ban blocked it? `sudo fail2ban-client status sshd`

Comment: Both currently and total banned are zero so I guess it's a no. Also I've already disabled ufw too.

Comment: Through the console, can your server ping something google(just to check if internet is working)?

Comment: Try this service https://vpn4.one/ to setup own VPN server on Vultr VPS